# cross domain iframe adjust height automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I searched over google as well as few answers from stackoverflow but none of teh solution worked for me. Is there any working solution available ,

Thanks you very much

Rohit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IFRAME need to send to the main page its body size.

For modern browsers you can use `parent.postMessage` from the IFRAME and have a listener in the main page to receive the value and resize the IFRAME.

For older browsers you can use tricks like passing data i.e. through `windows.name` or the `window.location.hash`
But with those tricks you will have to poll with a `setInterval` to check for changes.

Comment: Thanks you very much for teh details

Comment: here's an article and code example of refinements to this hash hack method: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/

Comment: And here's an easy example on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer/6940531#6940531

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit I would suggest taking a look at this website. This should solve your problem
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

A functional demo can be found here:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/

I plan to use this technique for a project of mine after I saw that I'm able to calculate the height across domain using query and postmessage. What's nice is it'll default to document.location.hash for older browsers.

Answer (score -2):

try calling a parent window function from your iframe