# setting Iframe height

Tags: javascript

In my Document I have a Iframe initially with a height of 700px
This Iframe contains a complex form, with different Selectboxes and Inputfields etc.

For example a Selectbox contains number of Inputfield to be displayed in Iframe.
initially the value is 0, and If I change the number of inputfields by Selecting a Different value from Selectbox
 e.g. If I select 10 then 10 input fields will be added to Iframe. as the height of iframe is fixed that why my Iframe will be a scrollbar

But this behaviour I don't need. I want to dynamically adjust the Iframe's height.

Comment: Is the IFRAME coming from the same domain? If yes why don't you use a DIV instead? If it's coming from another domain, here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521030

Answer (score 0):

if you're code is IN the iframe, and your iframe is on the same domain you should be able to do `window.parent` or just `parent` you should be able to access jQuery too like `parent.$`